# Json Deserialization can't access attributes of object

Tags: c#, json, serialization, win-universal-app

I got this class (by using json2c#):

```
 public class Friends
{
    public class Datum
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }

    }

    public class Paging
    {
        public string next { get; set; }
    }

    public class Summary
    {
        public int total_count { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
        public Paging paging { get; set; }
        public Summary summary { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is my poor try to perfom the deserialization:

```
                DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Friends));
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data));
                Friends x = (Friends)js.ReadObject(ms);
```

I thought I should be able to access for example Friends.Datum.name but it does not work.

My question is, what did I do wrong? How should I optimise my code?

I already got a DataTemplate for my ListView and I'm using the MVVM Pattern, so binding should be no big issue.

This is an example json response:

```
    {"data":[{"name":"XXX","id":"XXX"}],"paging":{"next":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/v2.5\/XXX\/friends?access_token=X"},"summary":{"total_count":2}}
```

XXX is secret

Comment: What does you `data` string to deserialize look like?

Comment: @Waescher Will update question in a sec.

Comment: Friends.Datum is a list, what does it mean to get the name of a list? You can get the name of items in the list.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Data is a list of Datum, so that will be fine.

Comment: No it won't. OP asked how to get "Friends.Datum.name". That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Yeah, just got confused of the bug from the page I used to get C# classes from jsonData, I ment RootObject.next for example

Comment: You're right @EvanTrimboli, I did not see the `Friends.Datum.name` you mentioned. I was talking about the way the json string is built with the `List<Datum>` to be accessed via `RootObject.data[x].name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the deserializer with the type of your `RootObject` because it has the matching properties `data`, `paging` and `summary`.

Answer (score 1):

The code should work if you are trying to de-serialize a RootObject not a Friends object. Also remember to use the using statement to ensure the Dispose is called on the stream.

```
DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data)));
{
RootObject x = (RootObject)js.ReadObject(ms);
}
```

Then you can access it like

```
x.summary.total_count
```

Comment: The property on the object (which matches the json) is called `data`.

Comment: @jsxl http://json2csharp.com/# has a bug there, I used copy and paste and it creates a c# class called datum -> bug found ;) Then I deserialized the Rootobject and now it is working thx

Comment: @Waescher no I realized the mistake he made between Friends object and RootObject due to Evan Trimbolis comment.  You beat me by a few seconds.  Cheers!

Comment: All fine, nothing to blame you for. It was more kind of a surprise because I would not have written my answer if you had the `RootObject` before.